# Can I programmatically hide the form input ribbon control above the keyboard in safari on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

For a prototype that I'm working on, we'd like to hide the ribbon that shows up above the keyboard on mobile web browsers on iPhones. This control allows users to cycle through form fields on a web page, and looks like this:

[image]

What I've tried:
1. Using contenteditable divs instead of inputs in the hopes that if the browser doesn't see traditional inputs, it won't show this control
2. Removing the tabindex property

Is it possible to programmatically control the visibility of this ribbon on iOS mobile web browsers?

Comment: It might be possible, but why would you want to do this anyway? Don't you want users to be able to easily cycle through form fields or be able to close the keyboard? Wouldn't you feel a bit frustrated if a website tried to take that control away from you while you were on their page?

Comment: @p.s.w.g We want to provide our own controls for cycling through form inputs along with some other context specific information, all represented in a similar ribbon. So we'd need to hide the browsers ribbon.